# Bad pointer in URL response

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, httpresponse

I am trying to upload a photo to Facebook from my app and all goes well when I upload and wait for it to finish, but when I press on upload then go back to the previous `view`, when the upload is complete i get an error

```
Thread 1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x9)
```

In the code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
_responseText = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:
     @selector(request:didReceiveResponse:)]) {
    [_delegate request:self didReceiveResponse:httpResponse];
}
}
```

It breaks on the `if`. I'm not sure how I would go about solving this.

Thank you

EDIT:
This is called before I go back to the previous view:

```
-(IBAction)shareToFacefook{
        [[self appDelegate] facebooking]; // checke that the user is loged in
        NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   labeledImage, @"source",
                                   [[MyStrings myLocalStrings] getBackLocalstring:FB_IMG_POST_TITLE],@"message",
                                   nil];

    [[[self appDelegate] getFacebookVar] requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"/me/photos?access_token=%@", self.appDelegate.getFacebookVar.accessToken] andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a memory management issue.  `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` generally means the memory address which is being accessed is no longer valid.

Are you using `retain` to increment the reference count for `_delegate` when you receive it?  If not, then it may have been garbage collected.  You should either use `retain` or make a `copy` of the delegate when you receive it.

Comment: where would i do that? this method is part of the `nsurl` delegate. it is all called in the background... what i do is `    [ [[self appDelegate] getFacebookVar] requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"/me/photos?access_token=%@", self.appDelegate.getFacebookVar.accessToken] andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];`. sorry it is so messy.

Comment: You should add that code to the question - the formatting in the comment makes it hard to read. :/

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:
1.check the Facebook.m
2.find the "dealloc"
3.you'll see the following code:

```
for (FBRequest* _request in _requests) {
        [_request removeObserver:self forKeyPath:requestFinishedKeyPath];
    }
```

replace it to

```
for (FBRequest* _request in _requests) {
        _request.delegate = nil;
        [_request removeObserver:self forKeyPath:requestFinishedKeyPath];
    }
```